# Discrete Functions are Non-Differentiable : Does this Require a Proof?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

I have always had the following question:

Consider a Mathematical Function which is purely Purely Discrete:

[image]

This question could not be more obvious - but in the example (left) where a function is mapping "colored shapes" to their "color": **It seems this function is clearly non-differentiable.** How (on earth) could we take the derivative of such a function?

I would like to approach this question more mathematically - for instance: **What mathematical arguments could be made to support the fact that this function is non-differentiable?**

The arguments that come to mind:

- This function is non-continuous and a function must be continuous for it to be differentiable (even though not all continuous functions are differentiable).
- This function likely contains an "Indicator Function" - and functions containing "Indicator Functions" are non-differentiable.
- This function is defined over a non-continuous set and is non-smooth.

**But in the end - what are the main mathematical arguments that can be used to establish that this function is non-differentiable?**

Or is this fact "so obvious" that it does not even require a proof?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Comment: "differentiable" needs a definition.  Algebraists often use $\frac d{dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$ even in discrete contexts, where no limit is defined.  Just for example.

Comment: To expand on lulu's comment, the "classical" definition of a derivative assumes we have a mapping whose domain is a non-empty open subset of a real normed vector space, and whose values lie in a normed real vector space. Those conditions allow us to make sense of the "linear approximation" condition of differentiability. Since the color mapping doesn't fit into this framework, it isn't differentiable (in the classical sense). But note there is no Universal Notion of Differentiability we can use to assess this color mapping without context, hence the need to agree on a definition.

Comment: In a similar spirit, one could say that integers are colorless, sinks are deaf, pencils satisfy no probability laws, parabolas are blind, and I'm irrational.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies!